# Android Gradle jar generation

Tags: java, android, gradle, groovy, build.gradle

I have an Android Project with a working `build.gradle` file. This is used to build an Android App. Additionally now I'd like to add my server code (plain java) to this project and setup the `build.gradle` file to run/start the emulator app like normal and also generate a `jar` file of the server code, which I can deploy onto my server.

I am new to Gradle and Groovy, so I am not sure about how to write the tasks correctly to achive my goal as described above. I'd really apprechiate some help in setting up this build file. I know I'll need the jar and java plugins but can't seem to figure out how to integrate everything into the Android build.

What I have so far in the (working) build file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'jacoco'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion '29.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = 1.8
        targetCompatibility = 1.8
    }
}

task jacocoTestReport(type: JacocoReport, dependsOn: 'testDebugUnitTest') {

    reports {
        xml.enabled = true
        html.enabled = true
    }

    def fileFilter = ['**/R.class', '**/R$*.class', '**/BuildConfig.*', '**/Manifest*.*', '**/*Test*.*', 'android/**/*.*']
    def debugTree = fileTree(dir: "${buildDir}/intermediates/javac/debug", excludes: fileFilter)
    def mainSrc = "${project.projectDir}/src/main/java"

    sourceDirectories = files([mainSrc])
    classDirectories = files([debugTree])
    executionData = files("${buildDir}/jacoco/testDebugUnitTest.exec")
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.esotericsoftware/kryonet
    implementation 'com.esotericsoftware:kryonet:2.22.0-RC1'
}
```

Comment: What about `compile files("whatever.jar")`?

Comment: @dan1st This seems to add the jar to the gradle project. Like a library. I want to generate a jar from my server code. That's not the same.

Comment: you should modify the build config of your server code project to generate the jar, not the other way around

Comment: Shot in the dark: move the problem up one level.  Have a "root" gradle project with the existing android one in one module and your server code in the other. Disclaimer: i have no clue about android related stuff, so i assume it would not mess up things as in taint the whole build/project in a way, that this won't work.

Comment: Thank you both! I ended up with kind of @injecteer 's solution and included the jar generation in the servers `build.gradle`.  The thing is, that the android gradle plugin can't generate jars at all. Only the Java plugin does that and these two aren't even compatible. The resulting project consisted of 2 modules (1 android and 1 java) both with `build.gradle` files and an overall project `build.gradle` file. So it's pretty much like both of you described :-)